# how sequential queries can be run one after another inside Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm a novice in BigQuery field. I've some legacy Teradata sql sequential codes which looks like -

/*************/
create table tab1 as (select x,y,z from table tab2);

update table tab1 set x = n where y= m;

create table tab3 as (select x,count(distinct z) from tab1);
/*************/

How to implement same type of code part in BigQuery? Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
S Pal

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, BigQuery does not yet support `CREATE TABLE` syntax, and requires [API call](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert). BigQuery team recognizes that DDL support in SQL is an important feature that many customers need, and such support is on the short-term team roadmap.